# i have some tasks on remote server. I am creating a python script to end the task but schtasks is not getting recognised

Tags: python

i have some tasks on remote server. I am creating a python script to end the task but schtasks is not getting recognised and also i am not sure how to user 'schtasks' in python. 'Adapter Issue' is the taskname on the remote server.

import os

```
os.system(schtasks /end /tn '\\Server\Adapter Issue')
```

Comment: `os.system()` expects a *string*. Do  `os.system(r"schtasks /end /tn '\\Server\Adapter Issue'")`. This quotes the whole command to make a string, and it needs to be a raw string because it contains backslashes.

Comment: i have tried the raw string but no luck. I have tried with other code also

subprocess.Popen(['schtasks.exe','/change','/tn','Kofax UK Check','/s' [r'//Server/'] , '/DISABLE'])

Getting below error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: You asked about `os.system()`. Now you have a different approach.In this case your problems are 1.  A missing comma after `'/s'`; and when you have fixed that, 2. The following element should be a string not a list.

Comment: In future when you change your code, [edit] your question to reflect the changes. Otherwise you are asking us to do that mentally while scanning code in comments. Help us to help you.

Comment: I assure you that raw strings do work as documented. To make your problem easier to solve, put the console command in a string variable and print it. Paste that at a command prompt and see what happens. If necessary, fix the string. Repeat that until the command actually works as expected at a console prompt. Then pass the variable to `os.system()` or (better) `subprocess.run()`. Don't bother converting the string to a list for `subprocess`. If you do, `subprocess` will simply turn it back into a string when it calls `CreateProcessEx()`.